# Statistics on filestream column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, statistics, filestream

When I try to create a statistics on a filestream column, I get the following error message:

> Column 'MyColumn' in table 'MyTable' is of a type
>   that is invalid for use as a key column in an index or statistics.

This is documented in the BOL page for [CREATE STATISTICS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188038(v=sql.110).aspx) and it's not an issue.

However, when I run a query with a predicate on the column (`IS NOT NULL`, for the record), a statistics is auto-created. Why is this disallowed for manual creation but still possible for auto creation?

The reason why I want to create a statistics manually is that I want to mark it `NORECOMPUTE` in order to avoid having to scan several GBs of data. I know I can let SQL Server auto create it and then mark it `NORECOMPUTE` later, but auto creation is triggered with the default sample, which I could override to `0 ROWS` in manual creation. I would also like to know if there is a reason for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you have applied the latest update for SQL Server 2012 - Cumulative Update 2 for Service Pack 3 as at the time of writing - and the issue persists, you should open a support ticket, or report the issue on Connect.

The underlying issue shares some common features with an existing report:

- [String summary - slow statistics creation on VARBINARY(MAX) column](http://web.archive.org/web/20160522092128/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/683303/string-summary-slow-statistics-creation-on-varbinary-max-column)

...which might give you some ideas for a workaround.

For example, there is a small chance that creating statistics on a computed column casting the column to *varbinary(200)* might work. That cast may also explain why the auto-stats succeeds while you cannot create statistics manually.